# What is the origin of the story where Vishnu disguises himself as a boy and gives Indra a lesson on impermanence?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, indra

As described here: http://mesosyn.com/myth2h-2.html

I've found the info that it comes from Brahmavaivarta Purana but this doesn't seem right as I've scanned through it and haven't found it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The story is described in BrahmaVaivarta Purana, **Krishna Janma khanda chapter 47.** Chapter is named as 'Shattering pride of Indra.' Lord Vishnu takes the form of a Brahmana boy and teaches lesson of impermanence to Indra. Some verses from that chapter are:

> Brahmana said:  O Hari!, I have come to meet you after coming to know about the construction of this astonishing city and to ask you some important questions. 
>  
>   What is the time schedule fixed for the construction of this city or otherwise for how long Visswakarma would be engaged in the construction work. 
>  
>   **No Indra has so far resorted to this type of construction.** No other Vishwakarma would be competent enough to carry out such a type of construction. 
>  
>   **On hearing the words of the boy, Indra getting arrogant** because of the immense riches, laughed and enquired from the boy again. 
>  
>   **"O boy how many Indras have you seen so far or heard about them and how many type of Vishwakarma?** You kindly let me know in detail. 
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   O best of the gods **even if one is able to count particles of dust on earth in spite of that number of Indras can't be counted.** This is the opinion of intellectuals.
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   Brahmana said "O Indra, I have created the entire group of the ants, one by one, **all these ants had been established on a throne of Indra one by one. All of them after having been born in various yugas have currently been born as ants.**

Comment: Thanks! Where may I find this text in full, if there is such a free English version?

Comment: @John Doe I have Sanskrit-English version with me... if you want it you can come here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/vedanta-and-philosophy and ask from The Destroyer... also if you want this specific chapter I can screenshot you it there... just ping me there...

Comment: I did find the chapter online, but thanks :)